# Fear-control the nerve system

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, programming

I want to prevent a situation when comes to me or to be ready. Firstly,we all have fear me too.The problem is when I get afraid my legs are shaking, I think I will fill out what I have eat and think think those fear thoughts with no stop. I lose my body control. I am not a usual guy I workout my body in daiLy bases and I have developed a lot of my body,meaning muscles.Moreover I play football 3 times a week,except of the body workouts.How can I control with some techniques when the fear comes? (Especially for me I feel my neck control everything but I want you to write general how to control the body in a situation like this).Thanks

Comment: You should be asking this question to a psychologist.

Comment: It doesn't be psychology theme issue only,my opinion.Even,asking psychologist will come to the point of given direction of physical action to it.The healthy way so i came here.Else ,he will tell you pills or something harmful for health I avoid it.

Comment: Fear is an emotion that can lead to physical symptoms.  You should investigate what the root of the fear is with a therapist.